# Start an android privileged app without ever opening it

Tags: android, privilege

I wish to create a privilege app (pre-installed or in a rooted device). Can I make my app run a service without the user ever open it? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal apps are installed in "stop state". It's means all their broadcast receivers are disabled until the user manually open them.

System apps don't have that restriction, so you can put your app in system partition, use broadcast receiver on BOOT_COMPLETED and start your service without user interaction.

Comment: Great Thanks, Maybe you can also help me with the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983261/marshmallow-intent-action-boot-completed